# How do I use tbb::parallel_invoke to run large number of tasks in parallel?

Tags: tbb, parallel.for

My problem similar to producer-consumer problem. For e.g. I need to run 999 producers and 1 consumer in parallel. Basically all 999 producers do the same task.

Comment: It seems unlikely that you are going to get significant parallel speedup if 999 producers are feeding a single consumer, unless the consumer is doing about 1/1000th the work of a producer.  In general, high fan outs or high fan ins are unscalable unless reorganized as a tree of lower fan out/in nodes.  Do the producers require mandatory or optional concurrency?  I.e., must they be interleaved, or can some be run to completion before others start?

Comment: Yes, the producers require concurrency. I am designing a data-structure that will be accessed concurrently by the producers and consumers i.e. producers produce and consumers consume at the same time. There could be cases with multiple producers and multiple consumers, multiple consumers and single producer as well.

Answer (score 3):

Parallel frameworks such as TBB (and Cilk Plus and PPL) focus on optional concurrency, which allows them to harvest just enough to keep the machine busy but not overload it.

If concurrency among producers is *required* then most TBB constructs are inappropriate.  For example, `tbb::parallel_for` makes no promise that it will run anything in parallel.  It just uses parallelism if it is available at the moment.  For mandatory concurrency, you will need a separate `std::thread` for each producer.  With 999 threads running, do not expect much speedup unless you have a machine with 999 hardware threads, or are keeping most of the threads sleeping most of the time (e.g. by using condition variables).